# Is there a tool that will find the linear combinations of these vectors to get the desired result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an initial vector (0101 0010 1011 0011) and sixteen possible vectors to add to it modulo 2 (listed below).

I want to get an output of all zeros (0000 0000 0000 0000) and an output of all ones (1111 1111 1111 1111).

The scalar on each of the sixteen additional vectors can be zero or a positive integer. Negative or non-integer scalars are not allowed. Integer values higher than one are allowed as scalars, but the final result will be modulo two.

My understanding is that I should use Gauss-Jordan elimination on the augmented matrix obtained by combining the initial vector with the sixteen additional vectors, but doing that by hand would be extremely tedious. Is there a (preferably free) tool that automates this process?

The additional vectors:

- (1100 1000 0000 0000)
- (1110 0100 0000 0000)
- (0111 0010 0000 0000)
- (0011 0001 0000 0000)
- (1000 1100 1000 0000)
- (0100 1110 0100 0000)
- (0010 0111 0010 0000)
- (0001 0011 0001 0000)
- (0000 1000 1100 1000)
- (0000 0100 1110 0100)
- (0000 0010 0111 0010)
- (0000 0001 0011 0001)
- (0000 0000 1000 1100)
- (0000 0000 0100 1110)
- (0000 0000 0010 0111)
- (0000 0000 0001 0011)

Comment: You can do this in any computer language and look at a column space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)